# EF Core, DB First: How can I get the model classes I want?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF and trying database-first. Looks mostly ok but there are a few cases where model class fields aren't quite what I want.

Table columns ...

```
[Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[InsertedAt] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
[UpdatedAt] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

Model fields ...

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public DateTime InsertedAt { get; set; }
public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
```

My model fields are all non-nullable so they will all get default values. Instead, I want Id to be nullable, and to get a constraint violation on an attempt to insert a null ID, because I want the client to have to create GUIDs. And I want timestamps to be autogenerated by the database for datetime columns on attemtpts to insert null.

I could hand-edit every model class to get what I want, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean code first to an existing database? EF Core does not support database first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features

Comment: Database first = "code first" against existing db (with EF Core)

Comment: What's your DB provider? I also get the same issue with Jet provider. Though I assumed that scaffolding is just not perfect so I settled with manually editing the models.

Comment: @SteveGreene I'm using 'dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold' to generate model classes from an existing database.

Comment: @PaoloGo Thanks ... that wouldn't be the worst thing if necessary. But there are so many options with DbContext and with attributes, that I want to see if there's a more 'proper' way. Or, if it's considered better to leave the db columns nullable, scaffold, and then ALTER TABLE on the db to make columns nullable.

Comment: In your case, I would retain the non-nullable types in your models and db. Then configure [`HasValueGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.hasvaluegenerator?view=efcore-2.1) for your entities.